# Ignoring/Skipping a call to startService

Tags: android

I have implemented a Service which extends IntentService for downloading a file by just passing a url string extra. I plan to maintain a List of urls within the service through the onStartCommand(). In onStartCommand(), I plan to do a check if the url already exists in the List, and if it does I don't want that specific call to the Service to be skipped or ignored.

Example:

1st call to DownloadService -> url1 -> startService

2nd call to DownloadService -> url2 -> wait for 1st call to finish

3rd call to DownloadService -> url1 -> skip this call because url1 is already being downloaded.

4th call to DownloadService -> url3 -> wait for 2nd call to finish

* Every time a download is completed I will remove the url from the list

Is it possible to ignore/skip a call to startService?

--------- EDIT ------------

Another solution I can think of is that I just handle the checking of duplicates within onHandleIntent(). Basically I will ensure that the url doesn't exist yet in the list before starting the download.